# How to make `lead` override `trail` in listchars

Tags: vimrc, whitespace, list, listchars

I have the following lines in my `.vimrc`.

```
set list
set listchars=lead:·,trail:⎵
```

Whenever I have a line consisting of only spaces, the character shown is `⎵`.

How can I make vim prefer `·` in this scenario? This seems like an edge case because the spaces are technically leading *and* trailing, but it is not clear how to override this behavior.

Comment: This behavior is hardcoded, you'll have to change the source code and compile Vim yourself.

Comment: Is there any reference to the fact that it is hard coded in the `vim` documentation, or is there a snippet in the `vim` source code brief enough that would clearly indicate this fact?

Comment: @Heptite wrote that comment, that's a good enough reference IMO. Anyway, there is no option that covers that specific behavior so, given that Vim is open source and all, feel free to dive into its code, add the option, and make it available for everyone via a PR.

Comment: You would need to change the following logic here: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/9a9432d3a223f7fbd902a0346030422ae0a97f0e/src/drawline.c#L2882-L2901

Perhaps just switching the 2 `else if` for `trail/lead` should work